# Lock widgets in place

Tags: app-widgets

Is there any way to lock widgets in place so that a long-tap won't make them move?

Comment: Hmm, you'd probably need a home screen/launcher that directly supports this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup - ADW Launcher has an option to LOCK DESKTOP which doesn't allow any changes to be made to the shortcuts or widgets.