# Can I lock desktop icons on X10 Mini Pro?

Tags: app-widgets, home-screen, sony-xperia-x10-mini-pro

Is it possible to lock the icons & widgets (i.e. disable the long-press-to-move function) on the Sony Ericsson X10 mini pro?

I saw this question - [Lock widgets in place](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9377/lock-widgets-in-place) - but it seems i may need to root the phone, and besides this issue, i am quite happy with the standard user interface.

Comment: Could you confirm whether you have the Xperia X10 mini pro or the Xperia mini pro?  Confusingly, they're not the same phone.

Comment: X10 mini pro, not the new Xperia mini pro.  It's running Android 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem as the only solution is to install ADW Launcher, as suggested in the other question.
And no, you don't need root to install ADW Launcher.

If you do decide to change launcher to ADW Launcher, Here's a link on how to lock the screen on the [Complete guide to ADW.Launcher](http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/wiki/CompleteGuideToADW#Lock_Desktop)

Comment: More research shows that the beta versions required root, but it is available from the Android Market now.  I'll give it a try as soon as I've got time to play :-)  Thanks

Comment: Pity that it's not a default function of Android to simply "lock" the home screen layout.  The X10 mini pro interface is actually nicely tailored to suit the tiny screen practically.

Comment: Tried it and it actually works very well!  Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en). In Nova Settings, `Desktop > Lock Desktop`.